# Python code shows outside figure, but not inside figure

Tags: tcolorbox, minted, python

I have defined the following `newtcblisting`:

```
\newtcblisting{pythoncode}[2][]{
  listing engine=minted,
  breakable,
  coltitle=CustomColorOne,
  colback=gray!25,
  colframe=CustomColorTwo,
  listing only,
  minted style=colorful,
  minted language=python,
  minted options={numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
  left=5mm,enhanced,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
            #2,
}
```

I have observed a couple of perplexing scenarios. For example, the following shows up as expected in the PDF.

```
\begin{pythoncode}[linenos=true,]{title=Example Usage of NumPy}
import numpy as np

X = np.random.normal(size=1000).reshape((100,10))

mean = np.mean(X)
\end{pythoncode}
```

But when I put it inside of a figure it disappears!

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{pythoncode}[linenos=true,]{title=Example Usage of NumPy}
import numpy as np

X = np.random.normal(size=1000).reshape((100,10))

mean = np.mean(X)
\end{pythoncode}
\caption{Example of using NumPy.}
\end{figure}
```

And just to add another layer of perplexity, if I include both versions of the Python code then it shows **BOTH** in the PDF.

```
\begin{pythoncode}[linenos=true,]{title=Example Usage of NumPy}
import numpy as np

X = np.random.normal(size=1000).reshape((100,10))

mean = np.mean(X)
\end{pythoncode}

\begin{figure}
\begin{pythoncode}[linenos=true,]{title=Example Usage of NumPy}
import numpy as np

X = np.random.normal(size=1000).reshape((100,10))

mean = np.mean(X)
\end{pythoncode}
\caption{Example of using NumPy.}
\end{figure}
```

I also tried with and without a caption, and with and without using `\label` and these did not seem to change anything.

What might be going on here?

Comment: Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but does it disappear entirely, or does it just move to another page?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That is not a stupid question at all! It really disappears entirely. Although, it does seem like there is a blank space around where the figure should be. I am using the float package with the `[H]` option.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I just tried without the `[H]` and the blank space moved to the next page, but did not show anything. It seems that something about the figure is included in the PDF.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I just noticed that even though I cannot see the figure itself, it does appear on the table of figures.

Comment: I see. I'm afraid I have no idea what's going on …

Comment: please edit your question to provide a complete small document that shows the problm

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the feedback. I tried what I thought would be a minimal example and that actually worked as desired. That implies that something is going on elsewhere in the document. I need to spend some time figuring out what that is.