# How to make tcolorbox with minted Python take up the entire document by shrinking whitespace?

Tags: tcolorbox, geometry, minted, python

I want to make a tcolorbox with minted Python code similar to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176174/how-to-pass-two-options-to-tcolorbox), including the size/aspect-ratio of the box, but with an additional requirement. I would like the rendered tcolorbox to take up the entire PDF document, notwithstanding some white space near the rounded corners. Or rather, I would like the tcolorbox to be of a similar size as if it were going to be placed in a document, but have all the white space around it tightened at or close to its border. Using that linked answer as an example, I would like the output be a PDF that contains this:

[image]

I seem to have eliminated the margins and the top whitespace with the geometry package by setting `top=0mm` and `margin=0mm`, but I am not sure how to remove the rest of the whitespace. I tried `bottom=0mm` but that did not work.

But there is still whitespace below.

With these isolated little code snippets I intend to put them into different slides and documents using the `\includegraphcs` command from `graphicx`. This in part to avoid [perplexing behaviour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635818/python-code-shows-outside-figure-but-not-inside-figure) that I suspect is coming from so many disparate packages being included in the preamble, but it would also allow me to reuse and share little snippets of code for document preparation.

I am using [Texmaker](https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) with PdfLaTeX, if that matters. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This [GitHub blog post](https://johnhw.github.io/separate_figures/index.md.html) looks promising, although *prima facie* it seems like steps have to be taken outside of LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable}


\newtcblisting{pythoncode}[2][]{
  listing engine=minted,
  breakable,
  listing only,
  nobeforeafter,
  minted style=colorful,
  minted language=python,
  minted options={numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
  left=5mm,enhanced,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
            #2,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{18cm}
\begin{pythoncode}[linenos=true,]{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading}
# indent your Python code to put into an email
import glob
# glob supports Unix style pathname extensions
python_files = glob.glob('*.py')
for file_name in sorted(python_files):
    print '    ------' + file_name

    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            print '    ' + line.rstrip()

    print
\end{pythoncode}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "*I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.*" Maybe so, but you nailed it! (+1)